# Error, me sale un error que no entiendo, estoy iniciando

Tags: php, mysql

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?> ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\EPWeb\Admin\Presentacion\Aval.php on line 48

Ese error me sale, estoy iniciando en php

```
<section class="content">

    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title">Aval</h3>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right" value="Añadir" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Añadir</button>

        </div>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
                    <th>Descripción</th>
                    <th>Acción</th>
                </tr>
                <?php

                $con = ConexionBD();
                $query= "SELECT * FROM aval";
                $ejecutar = mysqli_query($con,$query);

                where($mostrar == mysql_fetch_array($ejecutar)){ 


                ?>//esta es la linea 48




                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $mostar['idaval'] ?> </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $mostar['descripcionaval'] ?> </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <?php
                    }
                  ?>
            </table>
        </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Creo que en lugar de `where` quieres usar `while`

Comment: `while($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar)) {`

Answer (score 1):

```
where($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar)) {//este es tu error

while($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar)) {//esta es la sintaxis
```